# MongoDB. Remove the oldest element from array inside document

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I have this document:

```
[
  {
    "username_id": "user01",
    "passwordList": [
      {
        "tstamp": 101,
        "tempInd": 0,
        "pass": "aaaa"
      },
      {
        "tstamp": 102,
        "tempInd": 0,
        "pass": "bbbbb"
      },
      {
        "tstamp": 103,
        "tempInd": 0,
        "pass": "ccccc"
      },
      {
        "tstamp": 100,
        "tempInd": 1,
        "pass": "99999"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

What I want is to remove from the `passwordList` the element which has the lowest `tstamp` with `tempInd` equal to 0. This is my expected output:

```
[
  {
    "username_id": "user01",
    "passwordList": [
      {
        "tstamp": 102,
        "tempInd": 0,
        "pass": "bbbbb"
      },
      {
        "tstamp": 103,
        "tempInd": 0,
        "pass": "ccccc"
      },
      {
        "tstamp": 100,
        "tempInd": 1,
        "pass": "99999"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

This is my attempt:

```
db.collection.update([
        {"username_id": "user01" } ,        
        {"$pull":{"passwordList": { "$elemMatch": { "tempInd": 0 , "tstamp": {"$min": "$passwordList.tstamp"} } } } }
        ])
```

Any suggestion?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```js
db.collection.update(
  { "username_id": "user01" } ,
  [
    {
      $set: {
        passwordList: {
          $filter: {
            input: '$passwordList',
            as: 'filter1Password',
            cond: {
              $ne: [
                '$$filter1Password',
                {
                  $first: {
                    $sortArray: {
                      input: {
                        $filter: {
                          input: '$passwordList',
                          as: 'filter2Password',
                          cond: {
                            $eq: ['$$filter2Password.tempInd', 0]
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      sortBy: {
                        tstamp: 1
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
)
```

Working from the inside out:

1. The innermost `$filter` operator discards all array elements whose `tempInd` is not 0.
2. The `$sortArray` operator sorts the result of step 1 by `tstamp`, ascending. (note that `$sortArray` is only available in Mongo 5.2 and newer)
3. The `$first` operator returns the first element of the array returned by step 2 (this would be the element with the lowest `tstamp` whose `tempInd` is 0)
4. The `$filter` operator returns all elements of the `passwordList` array that are NOT equal to the result of step 3. (note that if the array has multiple elements that all match the result of step 3, all of them will be removed)
5. The `$set` operator sets `passwordList` to be the result of step 4.